# Double null check in single line

Tags: java, null, final

Is the following code the best way to check for `null` for two times in a single line for initializaing a `final` variable?

```
final String textValue = text != null ? text.getText() != null ? text.getText() : "" : "";
```

Comment: `text != null && text.getText() != null` - remember that `&&` and `||` short-circuit. Although, I would try to ensure that `text` can *never* be null and that `getText` can *never* return null, but perhaps that is just wishful thinking?

Comment: `if(text != null && text.length() == 0)`

Comment: You can shorten it by doing `text != null && text.getText() != null ? text.getText() : "";`

Comment: If you fell this is amazingly easy to understand for your fellow programmers, then please go ahead;-)

Comment: [Checking if condition for 'null'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787392/checking-if-condition-for-null)

Comment: Why is `textValue` even possibly null?

Comment: It's not a TextBox. It's of TimedText type in Android and it can be null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I'd probably use a single conditional with an `&&` condition instead:

```
final String textValue = text != null && text.getText() != null ? text.getText()
                                                                : "";
```

If you find you need to do this in more than one place, you may well want to wrap it in a method:

```
// We don't know what the type of text is here... adjust appropriately.
public static String getTextOrDefault(TextBox text, String defaultValue)
{
    return text != null && text.getText() != null ? text.getText()
                                                  : defaultValue;
}
```

Or adjusted to avoid calling `getText()` more than once:

```
// We don't know what the type of text is here... adjust appropriately.
public static String getTextOrDefault(TextBox text, String defaultValue)
{
    if (text == null)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    String textValue = text.getText();
    return textValue != null ? text.getText() : defaultValue;
}
```

Then you can simplify your variable declaration:

```
final String textValue = SomeHelper.getTextOrDefault(text, "");
```

Note that whether calling `text.getText()` more than once is a problem depends on your scenario - in some cases it would be a bad idea, and you should restructure your code to avoid it. We can't tell for sure, but it's worth considering.

Comment: @Aubin Why not? For this case it's presumably fine - if it was a "long operation" or had side-effects, then no.

Comment: @Aubin: Maybe. Maybe not. We don't really know without knowing the class involved.

Comment: For performance reason, I don't knwon (and I don't want to know) how complex the method getText() is. In the "method" version the ternary should be replaced by two lines.

Comment: @Aubin let the JIT handle this.

Comment: @Aubin: I've edited the answer to give that option, but quite often simplicity triumphs *potential* (but unrealistic) performance concerns. For example, I'm happy enough calling `ArrayList.size()` in a loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet, you eat the SO Scores, and others must be very very fast to beat you :-). Nice answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
final String textValue = (text != null && text.getText() != null) ? text.getText() : "" ;
```

Comment: @Craig not only that. Jon even improved his answer by far than this one.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Then you can upvote his answer and downvote mine . I have stopped taking anything from self proclaimed moderators.

Comment: I don't need to downvote yours since somewhat answers OP's question.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot: No-one suggested downvoting - there's no need to be aggressive about it.

Comment: As usual - SO is friendly place to ask and a hostile place to answer ;-/

Comment: @JonSkeet I say this because I feel stalked by some self proclaimed moderator . May be SO guys can figure this out from the recent activity !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot: Stack Overflow has millions of users. Being aggressive to everyone just because you've had a bad experience with some people really isn't a good strategy.

Comment: @JonSkeet Just like in real world ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "best" (most programmer friendly? most efficient execution?)

But a programmer friendly alternative could be:

```
final String textValue = (text != null && text.getText() != null) ? text.getText() : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this line is somewhere in a method. So this one will be more readable:

```
String value = "";
if (text != null && text.getText() != null) {
  value = text.getText();
}
final String textValue = value;
```